# segmentation fault after adding readonly property in sd-bus

Tags: c, linux, systemd, dbus

I use default sd-bus library produce by systemd. I modify example from
http://0pointer.net/blog/the-new-sd-bus-api-of-systemd.html
I add this lines to create a test property on dbus

```
/* The vtable of our little object, implements the net.poettering.Calculator interface */
static const sd_bus_vtable calculator_vtable[] = {
        SD_BUS_VTABLE_START(0),
        SD_BUS_METHOD("Multiply", "xx", "x", method_multiply, SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
        SD_BUS_METHOD("Divide",   "xx", "x", method_divide,   SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
        SD_BUS_PROPERTY("test", "u", NULL, offsetof(struct object, u), SD_BUS_VTABLE_PROPERTY_CONST),
        SD_BUS_VTABLE_END
};
```

and add object struct

```
typedef struct object {
    uint32_t u;
} object;
```

After compiling with modifications I have a Segmentation fault
Why I have it

Comment: Have you tried using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to catch the crash as it happens, and locate where in your code it happens?

Comment: Use, gdb said me this Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7f22878 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0

Comment: you need to compile with debug symbol and no optimization to get the full stack

Comment: gcc -g -O0 t.c -o my -lsystemd   /   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:340
340 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S: No such file or directory.

Comment: Check the callstack with the `bt` command. Walk up the callstack with the `up` command. Please [read the GDB documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Comment: there will be time - I will definitely read it, thanks!